# How to change the -h response on a Django Management Command

Tags: python, django, bash, command

If I run my command as python manage.py foo --help
It returns:

```
Usage: manage.py load_cartridge_types_delivery_windows [options] 

Options:
  -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
                        Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                        2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output

 ...

  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
```

At the bottom, it shows -h and the standard help message, "show this help message and exit". How do I change that help message to describe my command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the [`help`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.help) attribute on the class.